# Как не кэшировать страницу на которой объявляется cache manifest?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Имею ввиду это объявление:

```
<html manifest="demo.appcache">
```

FALLBACK и NETWORK не помогали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама страница, на которой добавляется манифест, в кеш попадает всегда.

А если Вы хотите на этой странице делать что-то хитрое, то надо подгружать дополнительный контент через AJAX, при этом описав адреса в NETWORK. И выставляя на сервере соответствующие.

Вообще эта штука задумана для кеширования статики. Если вам нужно из каких-то соображений не кешировать главную страницу, то очень вероятно что что-то пошло не так.